# fatal: not a git repository al ejecutar por segunda vez git status

Tags: git

Al momento de inicializar un repositorio, si ejecuto el comando `git init`, me sale el mensaje de que el repositorio fue creado, luego ejecuto `git status` y todo parece normal, ejecuto una segunda vez `git status` y me aparece el mensaje de error

> fatal: not a git repository...

En la imagen adjunta se puede ver lo que estoy explicando.

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás la sincronización de OneDrive esté molestando. Inténtalo en otra carpeta.

Comment: No es la sincronización de OneDrive el problema, de hecho, antes de tener este problema ya usaba Git junto con los archivos en OneDrive; el problema es que cambié la PC y en la nueva instalación de Git, me surgió este problema.

Answer (score 0):

No es un error, primero debes conectar tu git con un repositorio para ver el status de cambio entre el repositorio y tus archivos locales, el que ves es un aviso de una nueva característica de git

[Notas de la versión 2.30.2 para Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/ReleaseNotes.md#changes-since-git-for-windows-v2302-march-9th-2021)

Está implementa un sistema de monitoreo de archivos que se puede activar mediante `core.useBuiltinFSMonitor=true`.
El aviso que te da es que `core.useBuiltinFSMonitor=true` está obsoleto, y en su lugar uses `core.fsmonitor=true` (puedes desactivar el mensaje con `git config advice.useCoreFSMonitorConfig false`), sin embargo puedes tener varias versiones de git instaladas en tu Windows y pueden estar en diferentes niveles de revisión y durante la transición una versión puede entender solo la vieja palabra clave y otra las dos así que es mejor advertir al usuario y que el decida (aunque puedes configurar ambas por ahora)

En la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.31.0) nos explica que antes de está integración ya existía está configuración pero apuntaba a un comando externo para usarlo de monitor, también ahora dice porque es preferible tener un monitor integrado:

> el monitor del sistema de archivos puede acelerar los comandos de git que necesita para actualizar el índice en un entorno con muchos archivos, como `git status`. El monitor incorporado elimina la necesidad de instalar y mantener una herramienta externa de terceros

Comment: Si no es un error, quedaría sin responder es por qué el primer `git status` funciona y el segundo no. Además puedes tener repositorios locales sin remote.